# Pointers outputs confusing me

Tags: c++, c, pointers

**My code is here**

```
int main()    
{       
    int a=300;    
    char *p=(char *)&a;         
    printf("%d\n",*p);       
    printf("%d",*++p);    
}
```

output is

> 44
>
> 1

can any body explain it.

Comment: Write `300` in binary, the split byte by byte

Comment: Your code is rejected by both C and C++ compilers. Post valid code. And don't spam tags.

Comment: `300` ---> `0x12C`.... and little endian...

Comment: 256 * 1 + 44 = 300. Rings a bell?

Comment: http://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/44/en                                                       http://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/300/en  Little endian reprenstation of data in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know size of int data type is `2 bytes` or `4 bytes` depend on your system. While `char` pointer point one byte at a time.

Memory representation of `int a = 300;`

[image: ptr]
So, `char` pointer `p` pointing to only first byte as show above figure.

So, first time print **44** output.

Then,

```
printf("%d",*++p);
```

first `p` is increment and pointer point to next(second) byte. So, next byte output is `1`.

Comment: Nice illustration. How did you add it?

Comment: Best to just say at least 2 bytes. `int` can be anything the implementer wants. 4 and 8 are common today, but who can say what tomorrow will bring.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is too big to be represented over one byte because it's binary representation is at least `0000000100101100` (*depends on how much bytes `int` type gets. In this representation it gets 2 bytes, however, it can have 4 or 8, or other sizes, platform dependent*).

When you do `char *p=(char *)&a;` you only look on one byte of `a` - `00000001---00101100` - the right part, and it's value is 44.

When moving on to the next byte location (`++p`), the byte there is the left part (`00000001`) and it's value is 1

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting these values is because you treat an `int` memory location as two `char` memory locations (which is of course okay if you know what your're doing). Your original `int a` is represented in memory (byte view) like so:

`[0x2c=44] [0x01=1]` which makes `0x12c` when combined which is 300.

The following modification to your code helps to better understand this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    int i;
    int a=300;
    char *p=(char*)&a;
    for (i=0;i<sizeof(a);i++)
    {   
        printf("[0x%02x] ", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```